# Can an Uber Driver ID be used as a authentication tool for a third party app?

Tags: uber-api

We are building a similar type of feature app like Uber but rather than build out the driver authentication and verification pieces, we would prefer to simply Use the Uber Driver ID as an auth. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could key your user accounts off their Uber UUID. It's part of the [/v1/me endpoint](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-me). Driver-partners and riders authenticate against third party apps the same way.